# Finding a Nash Equilibrium of a Two-Players Game based on Best Response Functions - Taking a partial derivative from a piecewise, weird, function!

Tags: partial-derivative, game-theory, nash-equilibrium, piecewise-continuity

I need to find a nash equilibrium of a two-player game based on their best response function. The problem I have is that the functions I'm dealing with are somehow weird and hard to work with! So, let me start describing the problem for you:

There are two hosts in a city that are offering identical units, i.e., unit 1 (offered by host 1) and unit 2 (offered by host 2). The goal is to find the equilibrium price that both these hosts will have to offer in this two-players game. The profit function for each of them are described as follows:

$\begin{array}{l}
{\pi _1} = {\rho _1}{P_1} - {k_1}\delta  = \frac{{{P_1} - {P_1}^2 + b{P_1}{P_2}}}{{1 - {P_1} + b{P_2} + \mu }} - {k_1}\delta \\
{\pi _2} = {\rho _2}{P_2} - {k_2}\delta  = \frac{{{P_2} - {P_2}^2 + b{P_2}{P_1}}}{{1 - {P_2} + b{P_1} + \mu }} - {k_2}\delta 
\end{array}$

Where:

${k_1} = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
0,\, \, {\rho _1} \ge \theta \\
1,\, \,{\rho _1} \le \theta 
\end{array} \right.$

${k_2} = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
0,\, \, {\rho _2} \ge \theta \\
1,\, \,{\rho _2} \le \theta 
\end{array} \right.$

And:

$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{\rho _1} = \frac{{1 - {P_1} + b{P_2}}}{{1 - {P_1} + b{P_2} + \mu }}\\
{\rho _2} = \frac{{1 - {P_2} + b{P_1}}}{{1 - {P_2} + b{P_1} + \mu }}
\end{array} \right.$

The parameters of the problem are:
$0 \le \theta ,b,\mu  \le 1$

If you are wondering about the logic behind these formulas, the term $-k_i\delta$ is about the time when the utilization of the unit $i$ is below a certain threshold, say $\theta$, and if this is true, the host of that unit should pay some amount of money as the vacancy tax (you can assume that the government sets the constant $\theta$ and announces that if a unit is going to be vacant more than $\theta$ percent of some period of time, its host needs to pay some extra money as the vacancy tax). That's why I defined the indicator $k_i$ which indicates that when the utilization, $\rho_i$, is going to be below the threshold and if this happens, in the profit equation $k_i$ turns into 1 and the amount of vacancy tax, $\delta$, should be deducted from the profit. (Utilization is defined as the percentage of the time that the unit is busy, e.g., there is a host there using the unit).

Now that you know the problem, I need to solve what I brought below:

$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{B_1}({P_2}) = \arg {\max _{{P_1} \ge 0}}\left( {{\pi _1}} \right)\\
{B_2}({P_1}) = \arg {\max _{{P_2} \ge 0}}\left( {{\pi _2}} \right)
\end{array} \right.$

In other words, I need to first take a partial derivative from the profit functions, and then reach to a pair of $(P_1^*,P_2^*)$ in a way that:

$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{P_1^*} = {B_1}({P_2^*})\\
{P_2^*} = {B_2}({P_1^*})
\end{array} \right.$

Actually, if you're a bit familiar with game theory, you will notice that this is the time when neither of the hosts wants to deviate from their offered price (first-order condition). The problem, as you probably have noticed by now is that taking a derivative from the profit function is a bit complex mostly because of the indicator $k$ (at least I don't know how to deal with these functions while I want to find the optimal point).

Comment: One approach that sometimes works is to assume k has a particular value, solve the problems, and see if the prices you get are consistent with the k you assumed.